# How to calculate the required amount of flash memory when buying a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm going to buy the first STMF32103 series microcontroller, but I don't know how to calculate the required flash memory size.  Tell me how to calculate the memory required size of flash memory for tasks?

upd: I'm going to add a temperature sensor and a display to show the temperature.

Comment: As with all microcontrollers, it totally depends upon what you plan to do with it. A simple program will not fill the smallest RAM/FLASH, but if you start to add BLE, Wi-Fi, Cameras, etc., then you will quickly run out of space, even on the larger models. Get the biggest one that you can afford and then work within those limitations, with clever coding techniques, and/or avoiding certain libs (i.e. `stdio`). For example, just adding `sprintf()` to a very simple `main()` can take up 22kB of ROM. Maybe [edit] your question to clarify what your project will entail.

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers will tell you the ROM, RAM usage post build - an easy way to get an estimate and iterate from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a microcontroller for learning or for tinkering around, you should take the one with the biggest amount of flash you can afford.
Optimizing for smaller flash is usually done to save money, when producing devices in large quantities.